# Generics and Functions in C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, functional-programming, function

Here is some code, it won't compile but essentially want I want to create is a function that parses as CSV file and then converts the values in the CSV list to a specific type.

```
    Func<string, Func<string,T>, IEnumerable<T>> parser =(string csv, Func<string, T> newFunc) =>
    {
        List<T> items = new List<T>();
        string[] ary = csv.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (string val in ary)
        {
            try
            {
                items.Add(newFunc(val));
            }
            catch { }
        }
        return items;
    }
```

I want this function to be generic so T is the type that I want the CSV list to be converted to. The usage of this function would be something like:

```
 string csvList ="1,2,3";
        IEnumerable<int> list = parser(csvList, (string val) => { return Convert.ToInt32(val)});
```

However this obviously won't work because I haven't defined T. So is it possible to define T in a similar manner to generic methods like so:

```
    Func<T><string, Func<string,T>, IEnumerable<T>> parser =(string csv, Func<string, T> newFunc) =>
    {
        List<T> items = new List<T>();
        string[] ary = csv.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (string val in ary)
        {
            try
            {
                items.Add(newFunc(val));
            }
            catch { }
        }
        return items;
    }
```

And then use this like so:

```
string csvList ="1,2,3";
        IEnumerable<int> list = parser<int>(csvList, (string val) => { return Convert.ToInt32(val)});
```

Is there a way of doing something like this in C#?

-- Further Edit

Thanks to those of you have respond, in the code I have written I actually use a method like you have described, but I was wondering just a general aside if it was possible to do this as Func without the need for a method call.

Comment: How is this functional-programming? Because you are writing a C# function?

Comment: Side-note: if you are going to re-invent the CSV parser, remember to process quoted values (especially those containing commas) correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Your function signature for `parser` is syntactically incorrect and should be defined as follows.

```
Func<string, Func<string,T>, IEnumerable<T>>
    parser<T>(string csv, Func<string, T> newFunc)
{
    // implementation
}
```

Note, that when defining a generic function, you need to specify the generic parameters after the function name, and before the parameter list (see `parser<T>` above).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm missing something but I think this is what you need:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Parse<T>(string csv, Func<string, T> func)
{
   foreach(var item in csv.Split(new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
   {
      yield return func(item);
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the `items` can be removed as well, I missed that. I'll borrow it though.

Answer (score 1):

From the usage I would say you need a functuion that returns an `IEnumerable<>`, not a `Func<>`.

Which would simplify the whole thing to:

```
    IEnumerable<T> parser<T>(string csv, Func<string, T> newFunc)
    {
        List<T> items = new List<T>();

        string[] ary = csv.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (string val in ary)
        {
            try
            {
                items.Add(newFunc(val));
            }
            catch
            {
                // empty catch alert
            }
        }
        return items;
    }
```

And your usecase is missing a semicolon (after `ToInt32()`) :

```
    string csvList ="1,2,3";
    IEnumerable<int> list = 
      parser<int>(csvList, (val) => { return Convert.ToInt32(val); });
```

Edit, thanks to BFree: if you don't need the exceptionhandling to be inside parser  (and I hope that empty catch is there only in the sample code), you can eliminate the `List<T> items` and use `yield return` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.  I think this accomplishes what you're trying to do without a lot of hocus pocus.

```
string csvList = "1,2,3";
IEnumerable<int> list = parser<int>(csvList, Convert.ToInt32);



static IEnumerable<T> parser<T>(string csv, Converter<string, T> converter)
{
    string[] array = csv.Split(new string[] { "," }, 
                        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    T[] items = Array.ConvertAll(array, converter);

    return items;
}
```

**Update:**
If you want a single line, you could do it this way:

```
string csvList = "1,2,3";
var list = csvList.Split(new string[] { "," }, 
           StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x));
```

Comment: I actually use a method in my code but I wanted to know if it was possible without and using a Func instead.